# JQuery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a cell in a table that has a class of 'empty', i am then using a bit of code to find the id(cell number) so i can the find out what cells are next too it.

just too see if it works, i am trying:

```
console.log($('.empty').attr('id'));
```

but Firebug just returns 'undefined'

each cell has the class of 'box' and only one has empty as well so 'box empty'.

Any asssitance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your markup.

Comment: `$('.empty')` may return array of DOM elements. In that case, array itself does not have attribute

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 



$('.empty').each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
});

});

jquery above,

html for cell

<td id="B" class="leftbox" name="empty" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event,this.id)"> </td>

Comment: @nmyster You need attribute selector, not class. the name is empty, not the class! See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the DOM isn't ready. Put the code inside the on DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){console.log($('.empty').attr('id'));});
//or
$(document).ready(function(){console.log($('.empty').attr('id'));});
```

---

**Update:**

Based on the Markup you wrote,  the selector you need is attribute selector not class:

```
<td id="B" class="leftbox" name="empty" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" 
    ondrop="drop(event,this.id)"> </td>

$(function(){console.log($('input[name="empty"]').attr('id'));});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 

console.log($('.empty').attr('id'));
}

each cell has class of 'box' and empty cell has class of 'box empty' and each cell has an ID that is its number of cell.

Answer (score 1):

$('.empty') return an **array** of dom element, so you must use a loop (for, each...) to analyse results

```
$('.empty').each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
}
```

If you are sure there is only one element, you can use :

```
console.log( $('.empty:first').attr('id') );
```

Comment: He is sure there is only one. but the problem he mixed up class with name. see my answer and his comment on his question.